# VBA Code running in F8 But not in F5

Tags: vba, excel

I am having some trouble with my vba code. It seems to be running in F8 but not in F5. When it runs in F5, item is not recognized (shows up as item = nothing). I have pasted the code below.

```
Sub SlicerSelect()
    'On Error Resume Next

    Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate

    'Dim cache As Excel.SlicerCache
    Dim item As SlicerItem
    Dim Eval_Cell As String

    Offset_Cell = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A18").Address

    A = 1: AA = 0: AAA = 0

    For A = 1 To 2
        AA = AA + 1

        If AA = 1 Then
            Slicer_Name = "Slicer_Color"
        ElseIf AA = 2 Then
            Slicer_Name = "Slicer_Letter"
        End If

        'Set cache = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(Slicer_Name)
        BB = 0

        Do Until End_Switch = 1
            AAA = AAA + 1: BB = BB + 1: Eval_Cell = Range(Offset_Cell).Offset(0, CStr(AAA))

            If BB = 1 Then
                '''
            Else
                For Each item In ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(Slicer_Name).SlicerItems
                    If item.Name = Eval_Cell Then
                        item.Selected = True
                    Else
                        item.Selected = False
                    End If
                Next item
            End If

            If IsEmpty(Eval_Cell) Then End_Switch = 1

            Stop
        Loop

        End_Switch = 0
    Next A
End Sub
```

Comment: How does that item = nothing manifest itself and how did you know it's nothing? Is there an error message?

Comment: In terms of maintainability, I would create a subroutine (e.g. `MySlice`) between `BB=0` and `End_Switch=1` (inclusive). Then your main sub is just a pair of calls `MySlice("Slicer_Color")` and `MySlice("Slicer_Letter")`. Also, `End_Switch` should be a Boolean (`End_Switch = IsEmpty(Eval_Cell`), you should initialise `End_Switch` before entering the loop.  These changes will enable you get rid of `A`, `AA` and `AAA` (which is not used in your code). While these changes do not address your question, they may clean the code up and help locate the source of the error.

Comment: You have not included the relevant `BB=1` code - could the error be happening in there?